# How to print <div id="frm"/>

Tags: javascript, php

how to fix the code when we only want to print div id="frm". And hide the header and footer and button print once button clicked (I mean in print preview should only display content in frm)

```js
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Clinic System Management</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style2.css'/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print.css' media='print'/>
 
 <script>
 function printdiv (divname) {
  var printcontents = document.getElementById.innerHTML;
 var originalcontents = document.body.innerHTML;
 
 document.body.innerHTML = printcontents;
 
 window.print();
 
 document.body.innerHTML =originalcontents;
}
 </script>
 
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="hiderow">
 <?php
 include ('./includess/header2.html');
 ?>
 </div>
   <div id="printOnly">
   <div id="frm">
         <center><h1>Medical Certificate</h1></center>

          To whom it may concern, </p>
          
          This is to certify that.....................[name of the patient] </p>

          of ................................................................</p>
          
          Was examined and treated at the ........................................ [your clinic name] </p>
                             
          on ..........................[date] with the followig diagnosis.</p>        
                                        
          .........................................................................................</p>
          
          .........................................................................................</p>
          
          And would need medical attention for .......................... days barring complication.</p>
          <br/>
          
                                                ...................  </p>
                                                Doctor(s) Signature  </p>
</div>   
</div>       
<input type="button" onclick="printdiv('printOnly')" value="Print Here"/>     
</body>
</html>                                                 
<?php
include ('./includes/footer.html');
?>
```

```css
#printOnly
{
 display: inline;
}

#hiderow
{
 .no-print, .no-print*
 {
 
 display: none ! important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the id of your form in the getElementById part as shown below and then print it,this is a working code snippet,

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Clinic System Management</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style2.css'/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print.css' media='print'/>
 <style>
 #printOnly
{
 display: inline;
}

#hiderow
{
 .no-print, .no-print*
 {
 
 display: none ! important;
}
</style>
<script>
 function printdiv (divname) {
  var printcontents = document.getElementById("frm").innerHTML;
 var originalcontents = document.body.innerHTML;
 
 document.body.innerHTML = printcontents;
 
 window.print();
 
 document.body.innerHTML =originalcontents;
}
 </script>
 
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="hiderow">
 </div>
   <div id="printOnly">
   <div id="frm">
         <center><h1>Medical Certificate</h1></center>

          To whom it may concern, </p>
          
          This is to certify that.....................[name of the patient] </p>

          of ................................................................</p>
          
          Was examined and treated at the ........................................ [your clinic name] </p>
                             
          on ..........................[date] with the followig diagnosis.</p>        
                                        
          .........................................................................................</p>
          
          .........................................................................................</p>
          
          And would need medical attention for .......................... days barring complication.</p>
          <br/>
          
                                                ...................  </p>
                                                Doctor(s) Signature  </p>
</div>   
</div>       
<input type="button" onclick="printdiv('printOnly')" value="Print Here"/>     
</body>
</html>
```